# Cascading Soft Delete

Tags: sql, soft-delete

SQL has always had a great feature: cascading deletes. You plan it in advance and when it's time to delete something, BAM! No need to worry about all those dependent records.

However, nowadays it's almost taboo to actually DELETE anything. You flag it as deleted and stop showing it. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find a solid solution to doing this when there are dependent records. I've always manually coded the complicated web of soft deletes.

Is there a better solution out there that I have completely missed?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I hate to say it but triggers are designed specifically for this kind of thing.

(The hate part is because good triggers are very hard to write and , of course , cannot be debugged)

Comment: If you want to avoid writing a trigger procedure for every table that shall have archived cascading soft-deletes, you can take a look at my answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/53046345/835098). It is long but only because I wanted to avoid jumping right into the deep without explaining what each step does and why we use it.

Answer (score 44):

I've come up with a solution to cascading soft-deletes recently using Postgres 9.6 that makes use of inheritance to partition entries into deleted and non-deleted ones. Here's a copy of the document that I'm writing for our project:

---

## Cascading soft-deletes

### Abstract

In this document I describe our current approach to deal with deletion of objects in our Postgres database and I present the flaws of the current implementation. For example so far we don't have the ability to have cascading soft-deletes. Then I show a method that combines the strengths of Postgres' **cascading hard-delete** and an archiving approach that is easy to implement, maintain and that brings a performance boost in all search queries.

### About soft-deletes in GORM

In the [fabric8-services/fabric8-wit](https://github.com/fabric8-services/fabric8-wit) project which is written in Go we are using the an object oriented mapper for our database called [GORM](http://gorm.io/).

GORM offers a way to [soft-delete](http://gorm.io/docs/delete.html#Soft-Delete) database entries:

> If model has `DeletedAt` field, it will get soft delete ability automatically! then it won’t be deleted from database permanently when call `Delete`, but only set field `DeletedAt`‘s value to current time.

Suppose you have a model definition, in other words a Go struct that looks like this:

```go
// User is the Go model for a user entry in the database
type User struct {
    ID        int
    Name      string
DeletedAt *time.Time
}
```

And let's say you've loaded an existing user entry by its `ID` from the DB into an object `u`.

```go
id := 123
u := User{}
db.Where("id=?", id).First(&u)
```

If you then go ahead and delete the object using GORM:

```go
db.Delete(&u)
```

the DB entry will not be deleted using `DELETE` in SQL but the row will be updated and the `deleted_at` is set to the current time:

```sql
UPDATE users SET deleted_at="2018-10-12 11:24" WHERE id = 123;
```

### Problems with soft-deletes in GORM - Inversion of dependency and no cascade

The above mentioned soft-delete is nice for archiving individual records but it can lead to very odd results for all records that depend on it. That is because soft-deletes by GORM don't cascade as a potential `DELETE` in SQL would do if a foreign key was modelled with `ON DELETE CASCADE`.

When you model a database you typcially design a table and then maybe another one that has a foreign key to the first one:

```sql
CREATE TABLE countries (
    name text PRIMARY KEY,
    deleted_at timestamp
);

CREATE TABLE cities (
    name text,
    country text REFERENCES countries(name) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    deleted_at timestamp
);
```

Here we've modeled a list of countries and cities that reference a particular country. When you `DELETE` a country record, all cities will be deleted as well. But since the table has a `deleted_at` column that is carried on in the Go struct for a country or city, the GORM mapper will only soft-delete the country and leave the belonging cities untouched.

#### Shifting responsibility from DB to user/developer

GORM thereby puts it in the hands of the developer to (soft-)delete all dependend cities. In other words, what previously was modeled as a relationship from **cities to countries** is now reversed as a relationship from **countries to cities**. That is because the user/developer is now responsible to (soft-)delete all cities belonging to a country when the country is deleted.

### Proposal

Wouldn't it be great if we can have soft-deletes and all the benefits of a `ON DELETE CASCADE`?

It turns out that we can have it without much effort. Let's focus on a single table for now, namely the `countries` table.

#### An archive table

Suppose for a second, that we can have another table called `countries_archive` that has the excact **same structure** as the `countries` table. Also suppose that all future **schema migrations** that are done to `countries` are applied to the `countries_archive` table. The only exception is that **unique constraints** and **foreign keys** will not be applied to `countries_archive`.

I guess, this already sounds too good to be true, right? Well, we can create such a table using what's called [Inheritenance](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/ddl-inherit.html) in Postgres:

```sql
CREATE TABLE countries_archive () INHERITS (countries);
```

The resulting `countries_archive` table will is meant to store all records where `deleted_at IS NOT NULL`.

Note, that in our Go code we would never directly use any `_archive` table. Instead we would query for the original table from which `*_archive` table inherits and Postgres then magically looks into the `*_archive` table automatically. A bit further below I explain why that is; it has to do with partitioning.

#### Moving entries to the archive table on (soft)-DELETE

Since the two tables, `countries` and `countries_archive` look exactly alike schemawise we can `INSERT` into the archive very easily using a trigger function when

1. a `DELETE` happens on the `countries` table
2. or when a soft-delete is happening by setting `deleted_at` to a not `NULL` value.

The trigger function looks like this:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION archive_record()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    -- When a soft-delete happens...
    IF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE' AND NEW.deleted_at IS NOT NULL) THEN
        EXECUTE format('DELETE FROM %I.%I WHERE id = $1', TG_TABLE_SCHEMA, TG_TABLE_NAME) USING OLD.id;
        RETURN OLD;
    END IF;
    -- When a hard-DELETE or a cascaded delete happens
    IF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
        -- Set the time when the deletion happens
        IF (OLD.deleted_at IS NULL) THEN
            OLD.deleted_at := now();
        END IF;
        EXECUTE format('INSERT INTO %I.%I SELECT $1.*'
                    , TG_TABLE_SCHEMA, TG_TABLE_NAME || '_archive')
        USING OLD;
    END IF;
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

To wire-up the function with a trigger we can write:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER soft_delete_countries
    AFTER
        -- this is what is triggered by GORM
        UPDATE OF deleted_at 
        -- this is what is triggered by a cascaded DELETE or a direct hard-DELETE
        OR DELETE
    ON countries
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE archive_record();
```

### Conclusions

Originally the inheritance functionality in postgres was developed to [partition data](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-partitioning.html). When you search your partitioned data using a specific column or condition, Postgres can find out which partition to search through and can thereby [improve the performance of your query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3075248/835098).

We can benefit from this performance improvement by only searching entities in existence, unless told otherwise. Entries in existence are those where `deleted_at IS NULL` holds true. (Notice, that GORM will automatically add an `AND deleted_at IS NULL` to every query if there's a `DeletedAt` in GORM's model struct.)

Let's see if Postgres already knows how to take advantage of our separation by running an `EXPLAIN`:

```sql
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM countries WHERE deleted_at IS NULL;
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| QUERY PLAN                                                              |
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Append  (cost=0.00..21.30 rows=7 width=44)                              |
|   ->  Seq Scan on countries  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=44)          |
|         Filter: (deleted_at IS NULL)                                    |
|   ->  Seq Scan on countries_archive  (cost=0.00..21.30 rows=6 width=44) |
|         Filter: (deleted_at IS NULL)                                    |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

As we can see, Postgres still searches both tables, `countries` and `countries_archive`. Let's see what happens when we add a check constraint to the `countries_archive` table upon table creation:

```sql
CREATE TABLE countries_archive (
    CHECK (deleted_at IS NOT NULL)
) INHERITS (countries);
```

Now, Postgres knows that it can skip `countries_archive` when `deleted_at` is expected to be `NULL`:

```sql
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM countries WHERE deleted_at IS NULL;
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| QUERY PLAN                                                     |
|----------------------------------------------------------------|
| Append  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=44)                      |
|   ->  Seq Scan on countries  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=44) |
|         Filter: (deleted_at IS NULL)                           |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Notice the absence of the sequential scan of the `countries_archive` table in the aforementioned `EXPLAIN`.

### Benefits and Risks

#### Benefits

1. We have regular **cascaded deletes** back and can let the DB figure out in which order to delete things.
2. At the same time, we're **archiving our data** as well. Every soft-delete
3. **No Go code changes** are required. We only have to setup a table and a trigger for each table that shall be archived.
4. Whenever we figure that we don't want this behaviour with triggers and cascaded soft-delete anymore **we can easily go back**.
5. All future **schema migrations** that are being made to the original table will be applied to the `_archive` version of that table as well. Except for constraints, which is good.

#### Risks

1. Suppose you add a new table that references another existing table with a foreign key that has `ON DELETE CASCADE`. If the existing table uses the `archive_record()` function from above, your new table will receive hard `DELETE`s when something in the existing table is soft-deletes. This isn't a problem, if you use `archive_record()` for your new dependent table as well. But you just have to remember it.

### Final thoughts

The approach presented here does not solve the problem of restoring individual rows. On the other hand, this approach doesn't make it harder or more complicated. It just remains unsolved.

In our application certain fields of a work item don't have a foreign key specified. A good example are the area IDs. That means when an area is `DELETE`d, an associated work item is not automatically `DELETE`d. There are two scenarios when an area is removed itself:

1. A delete is directly requested from a user.
2. A user requests to delete a space and then the area is removed due to its foreign key constraint on the space.

Notice that, in the first scenario the user's requests goes through the area controller code and then through the area repository code. We have a chance in any of those layers to modify all work items that would reference a non-existing area otherwise. In the second scenario everything related to the area happens and stays on the DB layer so we have no chance of moifying the work items. The good news is that we don't have to. Every work item references a space and will therefore be deleted anyways when the space goes away.

What applies to areas also applies to iterations, labels and board columns as well.

## How to apply to our database?

Steps

1. Create "*_archived" tables for all tables that inherit the original tables.
2. Install a soft-delete trigger usinge the above `archive_record()` function.
3. Move all entries where `deleted_at IS NOT NULL` to their respective `_archive` table by doing a hard `DELETE` which will trigger the `archive_record()` function.

## Example

Here is a [fully working example](https://rextester.com/BMCB94324) in which we demonstrated a cascaded soft-delete over two tables, `countries` and `capitals`. We show how records are being archived independently of the method that was chosen for the delete.

```sql
CREATE TABLE countries (
    id int primary key,
    name text unique,
    deleted_at timestamp
);
CREATE TABLE countries_archive (
    CHECK ( deleted_at IS NOT NULL )
) INHERITS(countries);

CREATE TABLE capitals (
    id int primary key,
    name text,
    country_id int references countries(id) on delete cascade,
    deleted_at timestamp
);
CREATE TABLE capitals_archive (
    CHECK ( deleted_at IS NOT NULL )
) INHERITS(capitals);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION archive_record()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    IF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE' AND NEW.deleted_at IS NOT NULL) THEN
        EXECUTE format('DELETE FROM %I.%I WHERE id = $1', TG_TABLE_SCHEMA, TG_TABLE_NAME) USING OLD.id;
        RETURN OLD;
    END IF;
    IF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
        IF (OLD.deleted_at IS NULL) THEN
            OLD.deleted_at := now();
        END IF;
        EXECUTE format('INSERT INTO %I.%I SELECT $1.*'
                    , TG_TABLE_SCHEMA, TG_TABLE_NAME || '_archive')
        USING OLD;
    END IF;
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER soft_delete_countries
    AFTER
        UPDATE OF deleted_at 
        OR DELETE
    ON countries
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE archive_record();
    
CREATE TRIGGER soft_delete_capitals
    AFTER
        UPDATE OF deleted_at 
        OR DELETE
    ON capitals
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE archive_record();

INSERT INTO countries (id, name) VALUES (1, 'France');
INSERT INTO countries (id, name) VALUES (2, 'India');
INSERT INTO capitals VALUES (1, 'Paris', 1);
INSERT INTO capitals VALUES (2, 'Bengaluru', 2);

SELECT 'BEFORE countries' as "info", * FROM ONLY countries;
SELECT 'BEFORE countries_archive' as "info", * FROM countries_archive;
SELECT 'BEFORE capitals' as "info", * FROM ONLY capitals;
SELECT 'BEFORE capitals_archive' as "info", * FROM capitals_archive;

-- Delete one country via hard-DELETE and one via soft-delete
DELETE FROM countries WHERE id = 1;
UPDATE countries SET deleted_at = '2018-12-01' WHERE id = 2;

SELECT 'AFTER countries' as "info", * FROM ONLY countries;
SELECT 'AFTER countries_archive' as "info", * FROM countries_archive;
SELECT 'AFTER capitals' as "info", * FROM ONLY capitals;
SELECT 'AFTER capitals_archive' as "info", * FROM capitals_archive;
```

Comment: Thank you very much @cdunham! It's good to hear that the effort of creating this is useful to somebody. Let me know if this works for you or not. I hope you understand that you don't need GORM to get this working.

I'm sure with other systems this is not needed. In fact I'm more into event sourcing/CQRS/DDD these days where you get rid of the concept of state. State is what a thing looks like after events happened.

Comment: Instead of using timenow() in the archive_record() function one should use now() to make this work on newer Postgres versions.

Comment: Thank you @vkopio for this tip! I've verified that it works and updated my code above.

Comment: There is also one caveat to the archive_record function: it does not work if the table has generated columns as it tries to insert the generated value to the archive table which is not allowed.

Answer (score 7):

Foreign key constraints can do cascade updates. If you linked your tables on both the key and the delete flag, then when the delete flag in the master table changed, that change would propagate down to the detail table. I haven't tried that, but it should work.

Comment: This is insanely elegant IMO. The only problem with doing it is you can't use a NULL Delete_Date but instead have to use some arbitrary date like '9999-12-31'.

Comment: After thinking a bit more it doesn't work because if you soft delete a dependent record you get a key constraint error because the parent's delete date is different. To good to be true I guess ;)

Answer (score 2):

I think a benefit of the soft deletes is usually that not every table has a soft-delete flag, so the number of things needed to be cascaded is few.  The rows are simply unused in the database, but not orphaned - they are simply only referred to by deleted rows.

Like everything, though, it depends on your model.

Comment: Hmm, but then you have a database full of rows without seeing immediately which is used - right? You could join on the primary table, but if the cascade goes several levels deep, this could get messy. Or am I missing something?

Comment: It depends on the model.  In a relational design, if a deleted flag does not belong in the relation/tuple/table - i.e. it's not an attribute of the key, I would not put one.  In a star schema - you would put them only on the core tables.

Comment: If you give an example of a schema of a subsystem, I will show you which ones where I would put a deleted flag.  I would not, for instance ever put them on a many-to-many table unless you are keeping linkage change history, in which case, you would need to add effective dates as well.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what backend you're talking about, but you could pickup on your "delete flag" changing and cascade the change down using a trigger.